# Error when Parsing Pdf in selenium webdriver ruby

Tags: ruby, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to parse online pdf through automation testing in selenium webdriver ruby.I tried to do according to this url 
"http://blog.bitcrowd.net/test-rails-pdf-output-with-cucumber/".

I am getting error in this line

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new(StringIO.new(page.source))
```

It shows `PDF does not contain EOF marker (PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError)`

I am not using `capybara` gem so i can't use page.source instead of that i have used `driver.page_source`.I would like to know is there any equivalent method in selenium wedriver ruby as `page.source`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) and then putting

```
binding.pry"
```

in your test file so you can see what the webdriver gives you to play with by running

```
$> ls page
```

or similar.